# How can I find the most complete list of the names of Kaytn Massacre victims?

Tags: world-war-two, poland, resource, research-techniques

The [Katyn Massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katyn_massacre) refers to a series of mass executions of Polish prisoners by Soviet authorities during WW2. The number of victims is estimated to be over 22,000. How can I go about finding the names of all known Katyn Massacre victims?

Is there compilation of names that is regarded to be the most complete, and would such lists be available electronically?

Comment: Requests for primary sources and data sources such as this are often treated better than requests for secondary sources. (Rightfully so, I think, since this site is ostensibly meant to help historians do history research.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a blatantly off-topic source request.

Comment: There is [substantial community support](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/896/are-requests-for-references-appropriate-on-history-stack-exchangerevisited) for treating questions like this as on-topic. Unlike a question like "best books on James Madison," this question *can* have a definitive, single answer.

Comment: @twosheds no, "the most complete" is impossible to answer. There's always a chance there's another, more complete, list you don't know about somewhere.

Comment: @jwenting: There were a finite number of victims, therefore a complete list is a possibility. If the argument is "new information can arise," that is equally true for every possible question on this stack, but that is not a good reason for closing those questions as opinion based.

Comment: @twosheds sure, there also was a finite number of victims of Stalin's terror, yet no records were kept of all of them so it's impossible to ever know who all was affected (and in that case it's debatable which deaths to attribute to it as well depending on definitions, which may in the case of Katyn be easier). Fact remains that he doesn't ask for a complete list, but a "most complete" list, which indicates he knows or suspects there is no complete list, only fragmentary ones

Comment: As recognized, the choice in asking for a "most complete" or "best" list was deliberate. I would be shocked and amazed if they even recorded everything - and more so if it all persists to this day. New lists can and may emerge. Philosophically speaking, though, what we know about the past is subject to change based on new evidence. Not to sound too extreme, but every question about history is implicitly asking for an answer based on the best available information we have today. Many things are cut-and-dry, but non-source answers are also subject to change. I will make this comment on meta.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a source request.

Answer (score 3):

So far, I have discovered these (which I believe are compiled from the same sources):

- http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=cr&CRid=2236382
- http://katyn.org.au/Lista_Katyn.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Some Polish sources:

Online

1. http://www.osrp1939.policja.katowice.pl/Lista_Katyn-Pamietamy.pdf - "The list of people murdered in Katyń, Charkov, Tver, Mednoye, promoted posthumously"
2. http://www.katedrapolowa.pl/ofiary.php - "Polish army officers and policemen murdered by NKVD and buried in Katyń, Mednoye and Charkov, also citizens of the RP [Republic of Poland] from so-called Ukrainian Katyń List"
3. http://www.ogrodywspomnien.pl/index/historia,2,Katyn
4. https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategoria:%C5%BBo%C5%82nierze_Wojska_Polskiego_zamordowani_w_Katyniu - Wikipedia category (probably incomplete) "Polish army officers murdered in Katyń"

Printed (titles from Polish Wikipedia, to be verified)

1. *Katyń, lista ofiar i zaginionych jeńców, Kozielsk, Ostaszków, Starobielsk*, wstęp i oprac. A.L. Szcześniak, Warszawa 1989. ISBN 83-7001-294-9. [Katyń, list of victims and missing POWs, Kozielsk, Ostaszków, Starobielsk]
2. *Lista katyńska, jeńcy obozów: Kozielsk, Ostaszków, Starobielsk*, opr. A. Moszyński, Warszawa 1989. ISBN 83-85028-81-1 [Katyń list, POWs of camps: ...]
3. *Rozstrzelani w Katyniu: alfabetyczny spis 4410 jeńców polskich z Kozielska rozstrzelanych w kwietniu – maju 1940 r., według źródeł sowieckich, polskich i niemieckich*, red. M. Skrzyńska-Pławińska, Warszawa 1995. ISBN 83-86713-11-9.[Shot in Katyń: alphabetic index of 4410 Polish POWs from Kozielsk, shot in April-May 1940, by Soviet, Polish and German sources]
4. J. Tucholski: *Mord w Katyniu. Kozielsk, Ostaszków, Starobielsk: lista ofiar*, Warszawa 1991. ISBN 83-211-1408-3. [Katyń murder. Kozielsk, Ostaszków, Starobielsk: list of victims]

Comment: Your 3rd online source includes names I did not find in other electronic sources. I am currently affiliated with a university and will try to locate the those texts if I can.

Comment: You can try searching by Polish term "lista zamordowanych w Katyniu" or "pomordowanych" instead of "zamordowanych" (both words mean "murdered", however "pomordowanych" is more common in this context - the difference is that "pomordowanych" is referring rather to a mass kill). I did this query, however other pages lead to first three sources. If possible, try finding paper sources